# Getting message queue from another process in Elixir

Tags: elixir, message-queue

I'm trying to get message queue from one process into another. It works like this: first process (GenServer) starts, it starts second process by request. Then I do cast in the first process and this cast does call to the second process. Before call to the second process I', trying to get it's message queue and always get an empty one.

```
defmodule First do
use GenServer

def start_link() do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %{}, name: __MODULE__)
end

def init(state) do
    {:ok, Map.put(state, :process_list, [])}
end

def handle_call({:start_second, name}, _from, state) do

    process_list = Map.get(state, :process_list)
    {:ok, pid} = SecondProcess.start(name)
    {:ok, Map.put(state, :process_list, [{name, pid}|process_list])}

    {:reply, reply, state1}
end
def handle_call(_msg, _from, state) do
    {:reply, :ok, state}
end

def handle_cast({:test, name}, state) do

    process_list = Map.get(state, :process_list)
    {_, pid} = List.keyfind(process_list, name, 0)

    :erlang.process_info(pid, :messages) |> IO.inspect

    SecondProcess.test(pid)

    IO.puts("TEST FINISHED")

    {:noreply, state}
end
def handle_cast(_msg, state) do
    {:noreply, state}
end

def start_second_process(name) do
    GenServer.call(__MODULE__, {:start_second, name})
end

def test(user_name) do
    GenServer.cast(__MODULE__, {:test, user_name})
    IO.puts("TEST STARTED")
end
```

end

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to accomplish here, but I do feel compelled to point out a couple of antipatterns: 1) GenServers should not launch other processes, leave that to Supervisors. The Single Responsibility Principle holds in Elixir just as well. 2) You probably never want to use `start`, but always `start_link`. Having processes go off without something to get notified of completion, etcetera, is not what you want. If only because linked processes show up nicer in the Erlang observer application tree.

Answer (score 0):

Sending a call or a cast to a GenServer is done with normal message passing. So your call for the process inbox will be queued in the process inbox. Due to the FIFO nature of the queue, your cast will only be handled once all other messages in the queue have been processed. Thus you'll only see the messages that were queued after you called cast.